# PowerShell - One IE browser with multiple tabs

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, powershell, browser, tabs

Credential Variables

```
$usernameMI = "myusername"
$passwordMI = "mypassword"
$usernameBES = "myusername2"
$passwordBES = "mypassword"
$domainBES = "thedomain"
```

1st Site

```
$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.visible = $true
$ie.navigate("https://mobility-vsp4.corp.com/mifs/login.jsp")
while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) {start-sleep -m 100}
$ie.document.getElementById("username").value= $usernameMI
$ie.document.getElementById("password").value = $passwordMI
$ie.document.getElementById("login-btn").click();
```

2nd Site

```
$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.navigate("https://chq-exch-bas01.corp.dsfsd.com/webconsole/app?consoleSId=&page=Login&service=page")
while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) {start-sleep -m 100}
$ie.document.getElementById("overridelink").click()
$ie.navigate("https://chq-exch-bas01.corp.sdfsdf.com/webconsole/app?consoleSId=&page=Login&service=page")
while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) {start-sleep -m 100}
$ie.visible = $true
$ie.document.getElementById("text_username").value= $usernameBES
$ie.document.getElementById("text_password").value = $passwordBES
$ie.document.getElementById("text_domain").value = $domainBES
$ie.document.getElementById("loginImage").click()
```

3rd Site

```
$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.navigate("https://chq-exch-bdsx.corp.sdfsd.com:38443/webconsole/app?page=ReLogin&service=page")
while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) {start-sleep -m 100}
$ie.document.getElementById("loginLink").click()
$ie.navigate("https://chq-exch-bdsx.corp.sdfsdf.com:38443/webconsole/app?consoleSId=&page=Login&service=page")
while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) {start-sleep -m 100}
$ie.visible = $true
$ie.document.getElementById("text_username").value= $usernameBES
$ie.document.getElementById("text_password").value = $passwordBES
$ie.document.getElementById("text_domain").value = $domainBES
$ie.document.getElementById("loginImage").click()
```

I would like to have all the sites populate in one browser with multiple tabs while logging into each site - is this possible?

> This is what I tried, although it is still not acknowledging Sites 2 and 3. It leaves both 2 & 3 at the loggin page.

```
$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.Navigate("https://mobility-vsp1.dsdfss.com/mifs/login.jsp");
while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) {start-sleep -m 100}
$ie.document.getElementById("username").value= $usernameMI
$ie.document.getElementById("password").value = $passwordMI
$ie.document.getElementById("login-btn").click();

while($ie.busy -eq $ture) 
{
start-sleep -milliseconds 10000;
}

$ie.Navigate2("https://chq-exch-bas01.corp.sdfsd.com/webconsole/app?consoleSId=&page=Login&service=page", $navOpenInBackgroundTab);
$ie.document.getElementById("overridelink").click()
$ie.document.getElementById("text_username").value= $usernameBES
$ie.document.getElementById("text_password").value = $passwordBES
$ie.document.getElementById("text_domain").value = $domainBES
$ie.document.getElementById("loginImage").click()

while($ie.busy -eq $ture) 
{
start-sleep -milliseconds 10000;
}

$ie.Navigate2("https://chq-exch-bdsx.corp.sdfsdf.com:38443/webconsole/app?page=ReLogin&service=page", $navOpenInBackgroundTab);
$ie.document.getElementById("loginLink").click()
$ie.document.getElementById("text_username").value= $usernameBES
$ie.document.getElementById("text_password").value = $passwordBES
$ie.document.getElementById("text_domain").value = $domainBES
$ie.document.getElementById("loginImage").click()

$ie.visible = $true
```

Comment: read this answer: http://superuser.com/a/208886/191450

Comment: @CB Thank you this worked. Although I am having trouble logging into site 2 and 3. Any suggestions on how to reference sites 2 and 3 in the script?

Comment: @CB. When I say reference I mean allow the tabs to call my variables.

Answer (score 0):

this way I can open more than one tab in a single IE

```
$ie = New-Object -ComObject "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.Navigate("http://www.microsoft.com")
$ie.Navigate2("http://www.google.com" , 2048)
$ie.Navigate2("http://www.outlook.com" , 2048)
$ie.Visible = $true
```

add your code to the page before calling the next one and should work.

Comment: Thanks again, I just tried what you suggested but still having a problem with calling the variables on sites 2 & 3. Please see the edits I made to the Code above.

Comment: Here is the error I am getting....

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:39 char:51
+     $ie.document.getElementById("loginLink").click <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (click:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware that I'm responding to a question that's almost four years old, but I was having a similar problem with trying to access JavaScript variables on multiple tabs. What I ended up doing was creating a shell application COM object, using that to access and store each tab in its own variable, and then using `IHTMLDocument3_getElementByID()` to access each tab's DOM. For some reason, the plain `getElementByID()` method doesn't work when you have multiple tabs.

The code would look something like this:

```
$sa = New-Object -com Shell.Application
$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.Navigate("https://mobility-vsp1.dsdfss.com/mifs/login.jsp");
while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) {start-sleep -m 100}
#the full URL doesn't have to be entered to return a match in the code below
$tab1 = $sa.Windows() | Where-Object {$_.locationURL -match "mobility-vps1.dsdfss.com"} 
$tab1.document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("username").value= $usernameMI
$tab1.document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("password").value = $passwordMI
$tab1.document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("login-btn").click();

while($ie.busy -eq $true) 
{
start-sleep -milliseconds 10000;
}

$ie.Navigate2("https://chq-exch-bas01.corp.sdfsd.com/webconsole/app?consoleSId=&page=Login&service=page", $navOpenInBackgroundTab);
$tab2 = $sa.Windows() | Where-Object {$_.locationURL -match "chq-exch-bas01.corp.sdfsd.com"}
$tab2.document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("overridelink").click()
$tab2.document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("text_username").value= $usernameBES
$tab2.document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("text_password").value = $passwordBES
$tab2.document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("text_domain").value = $domainBES
$tab2.document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("loginImage").click()

while($ie.busy -eq $true) 
{
start-sleep -milliseconds 10000;
}

$ie.Navigate2("https://chq-exch-bdsx.corp.sdfsdf.com:38443/webconsole/app?page=ReLogin&service=page", $navOpenInBackgroundTab);
$tab3 = $sa.Windows() | Where-Object {$_.locationURL -match "chq-exch-bdsx.corp.sdfsdf.com"}
$tab3.document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("loginLink").click()
$tab3.document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("text_username").value= $usernameBES
$tab3.document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("text_password").value = $passwordBES
$tab3.document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("text_domain").value = $domainBES
$tab3.document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("loginImage").click()

$ie.visible = $true
```